# Problem with convergence of Magnus expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve a system of ODEs with the Magnus expansion. Unfortunately, even though I know the solution exists (and I also exactly know it), it seems the Magnus expansion is not converging. My system of ODEs is a bit too complicated to write here, but a toy model that exhibits the same problem is the following:
$$
\Delta'=B \Delta, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$
with $\Delta(x)=(y(x), z(x))$ and 
$$
B=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & \frac{1}{x} \\
    1 & \frac{1}{x} \\
  \end{array}
\right). ~~~~~(2)
$$
I set the initial conditions at $x_i=10^{-2}$ and I'm only interested in solving in the range $x\in[x_i,1]$. In this case, the system can actually be solved analytically and the solution is given in terms of the  exponential integral function $Ei(z)$ (it's too long so, I won't give it here).

Trying to solve Eq. (1) with the Magnus expansion fails, as it seems the series doesn't converge since the integral of the norm $\int_0^T ||B(x)||_2 dx $ doesn't converge for any $T$.

My question is: **Is there any way to fix this?**

*What I have tried:*

1) Change of variables (from $x$ to $a$):

This doesn't work as $\Delta'(x)=\frac{d\Delta}{dx}=\frac{d\Delta}{da}\frac{da}{dx}$ and Eq (1) becomes:

$$
\Delta'(a)=B \frac{dx}{da} \Delta(a), \\
=\tilde{B}\Delta(a)
$$
In this case the hope is that $\tilde{B}$ will not be singular, however using the properties of the norm $\int_0^T ||\tilde{B}(a)||_2 da=\int_0^T ||B(x)||_2 \frac{dx}{da} da= \int_0^T ||B(x)||_2 dx$, which again doesn't converge.

2) Redefining $\Delta$:

Assume that $\Delta(x)=\Gamma(x) \tilde{\Delta}(x)$, then the system of Eq.(1) can be written as 
$$
\tilde{\Delta}'=\Gamma^{-1}(B\Gamma-\Gamma') \tilde{\Delta}, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(3)
$$

One solution would then be to demand that $\Gamma^{-1}(B\Gamma-\Gamma')$ is the 2x2 Identity matrix $I_2$, ie we can rewrite (3) as 
$$
\tilde{\Delta}'= \tilde{\Delta}
$$
but then this means that $\Gamma$ satisfies $\Gamma'=(B-I_2)\Gamma$, which brings us back to square one.

Any help is appreciated.

PS The Matrix to the full problem (whose analytical solution is also known) is given by 
$$
B=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \frac{27}{20 x^2} & \frac{243 + 10 (27 - 20 x) x}{
  20 \sqrt{30} x^{\frac{5}{2}}} \\
    -\frac{3 \sqrt{\frac{3}{10}}}{2 x^{\frac{3}{2}}} & -\frac{
   27 + 20 x}{20 x^2} \\
  \end{array}
\right), ~~~~~(4)
$$
while the initial conditions are $\Delta_0=(\frac{91}{100}, -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{10}}}{10}$) at $x_0=10^{-2}$.

Comment: Do you *have* to solve the system with the Magnus expansion?  If not, why not try the [Peano-Baker series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix#Peano-Baker_series)?

Comment: @user539887 Oh, I didn't know this, thanks! Does it also have similar convergence issues? Of course, I will try it and report back if it works :)

Comment: If the problem is the singularity at zero this should show up in the Peano series also. One option might be to solve from an initial condition $x_0 > 0$, and then take the Peano or Magnus series forwards and backwards in time

Comment: @Nadiels I'm only interested in solving in the range $x\in[x_0,1]$ where $x_0\sim 10^{-2}$. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: In that case unless I am missing something then things should work out fine? When you say the Magnus series isn't coverging are you trying to solve it over the whole interval $[x_0, 1]$ or are you breaking the interval in to smaller subintervals and then solving recursively?

Comment: I tried to solve it in the whole interval $[x_0,1]$. Hopefully, your suggestion will work (I'm doing the calcs now).

Comment: @user539887 The Peano series seems to be working, many thanks! Also many thanks to Nadiels. Out of curiosity, it would be nice to also see why the Magnus expansion fails, so I will leave this question open and offer a bounty in a few days.

Comment: Hmm, I spoke too early it seems. While it works well with the simple example, the real problem seems to converge really badly: 900% difference from the analytical solution at x=0.02! I'll update the question with the full matrix in case someone has an insight.